# Elasticsearch query - checking input value

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to check search value from input with some rules. For example i need to check if value has lenght of 7, if is it only number and doesn't have white space (ie if is id).

Is it possible to do it with elastic search query or do I need to check string value before sending it to elastic search query? I use lambda node function with elastic client javascript for making queries to elasticsearch.

Comment: That's typically something your client code should do, because depending on what you find out, your query might not look the same.

Comment: so elasticsearch (script method) does not support all these checks

Comment: Please show what kind of query you're running. You can do stuff with scripting, but only in certain cases and it's not advisable to run scripts if not necessary

Comment: I need to check is string an id(numbers length 7), barcode(number and letter length 13), and product code (number and letter length 21). If it id I will query only id. If it is neither of these i query other multiple fileds like category, name, desc... Query need to be fast. Index have 400 000 docs.  Do you have some links from docs? I need to document everything. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Ismeet what Val says is correct, generally you would do these checks in your client before your query but perhaps the regexp query could be useful to you? Its documentation is [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html)